# How to check userName and password using Identity core's signInManager without setting cookie or requiring HttpContext

Tags: blazor, identity

I want only to check user name and password against input, But since I execute my app inside webview I don't have HttpContext and so can't set coockies.

How do I validate userName and password without requiring HttpContext or setting coockies, Using signInManager or any other way? In Asp.Net Core Identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way to do this with first checking userName and Password for correctness and then with creating a custom **AuthenticationStateProvider** in Blazor for authorization.